# How to fix a 500 OOPS: vsf_sysutil_recv_peek error in EC2 instance?

Tags: linux, ftp, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Recently, after converting a store-backed instance to a EBS-backed I got some warnings, but I have a working AMI. However, I was not able to connect to vsftpd from my ftp client. It throws the error:
500 OOPS: vsf_sysutil_recv_peek

The solution proposed in some sites for this problem is to load capability module:

```
$ modprobe capability
```

But I got this:

```
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.16.33-xenU/modules.dep: No such file or directory
```

How do I resolve this problem? Keep in mind that I can access to my instance via SFTP using WinSCP or another client, but I would prefer to resolve this to avoid using it.

Using CentOS 5.7

Answer (score 1):

Download it here http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads/ec2-modules-2.6.16.33-xenU-x86_64.tgz

copy 2.6.16.33-xenU to /lib/modules/
This solved my issue when I was using fuse. command modprobe fuse gave me the same error
Hope this helps