# FTP upload no data error

Tags: ftp, ftplib

I'm getting a weird error that only appears when I try to run this code on a Linux server, but it works perfectly on my local Mac. I'm not sure if anyone else has ran into this issue and can give me insight.

```
 import ftplib
 import sys, os

 files_to_drop = set()
 server = ""
 username = ""
 password = ""
 ftp_connection = ftplib.FTP(server, username, password)
 remote_path = "/incoming/"
 ftp_connection.cwd(remote_path)
 local_path = '/var/www/analytics/'

 def deliver_via_ftp():
    fh = open(local_path + files_to_drop[0], 'rb')
    ftp_connection.storbinary('STOR {}'.format(files_to_drop[0]), fh)
    fh.close()
```

The error I'm receiving on the Linux machine is below:

```
*cmd* 'CWD /incoming/'
*put* 'CWD /incoming/\r\n'
*get* '250 Directory successfully changed.\n'
*resp* '250 Directory successfully changed.'
starting to drop files.
*cmd* 'TYPE I'
*put* 'TYPE I\r\n'
*get* '500 OOPS: vsf_sysutil_recv_peek: no data\n'
*resp* '500 OOPS: vsf_sysutil_recv_peek: no data'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage_batches.py", line 258, in <module>
    m.run()
  File "manage_batches.py", line 253, in run
    self.__deliver_via_ftp()
  File "manage_batches.py", line 215, in __deliver_via_ftp
    self.ftp_connection.storbinary('STOR {}'.format(file_name), fh)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 502, in storbinary
    self.voidcmd('TYPE I')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 277, in voidcmd
    return self.voidresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 250, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 245, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 500 OOPS: vsf_sysutil_recv_peek: no data
```

I found a thread here (https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp/issues/50) regarding the problem, but seems to point to repeatedly opening and closing of the connection. I'm reusing the same connection for all files and it works on my Mac.

Debug trace on Mac:

```
*cmd* 'CWD /incoming/'
*put* 'CWD /incoming/\r\n'
*get* '250 Directory successfully changed.\n'
*resp* '250 Directory successfully changed.'
*cmd* 'TYPE I'
*put* 'TYPE I\r\n'
*get* '200 Switching to Binary mode.\n'
*resp* '200 Switching to Binary mode.'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*put* 'PASV\r\n'
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (<hidden IP>,11,133).\n'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (<hidden IP>,11,133).'
*cmd* 'STOR 11062017_0812_AM.txt'
*put* 'STOR 11062017_0812_AM.txt\r\n'
*get* '150 Ok to send data.\n'
*resp* '150 Ok to send data.'
*get* '226 Transfer complete.\n'
*resp* '226 Transfer complete.'
file dropped /Users/f/Desktop/bucket/11062017_0812_AM.txt
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

EDIT: I cleaned up the code to remove the class structure and I added the debug output set to level 2.

Comment: Do you get the problem with the first file already? If you do, please edit your question to show a simple code for uploading a single file, with no fancy classes and methods ([mcve]) + Also show us ftplib log (`FTP.set_debuglevel`) from both machines.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you. I have updated the question to include your two points.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure which is the first file? Are you referring to running this on my local vs linux server?

Comment: I mean the first file in `files_to_drop`.

Comment: Hi Martin, I added the requested items. It appears that it fails when it attempts to switch to 'binary mode' step.

Comment: What FTP server is that? Isn't it [EC2 server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8128541/850848)?

Comment: It's a DigitalOcean instance.

Comment: Did you try to connect and transfer a file with command-line `ftp` client from the Linux machine?

Comment: Strangely enough it worked just fine from the command line. I'm not experienced enough to understand how I should interpret that. Is the cron user somehow treating the script differently than my user when the script is run? I also checked permissions on the folder that holds the files and it's open to all. I did a chmod 666.

Comment: What did you try exactly in command-line client? Show us. Did you try switching to binary mode? Why "cron"? You never mentioned cron previously.